# Binding ListView ItemTemplate to Key and Value of Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` that contains some data I want to display in a `ListView`. The `ListView` definitely "sees" the right number of items (because I see the appropriate number of colons from the second `TextBlock`) but it doesn't display either the `Key` or the `Value` binding.

Do I need a `Converter` or something?

Do I need to change and use an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` instead?

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" IsItemClickEnabled="False" 
          SelectionMode="None" IsHitTestVisible="False"
          IsSwipeEnabled="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolInfoText}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

public Dictionary<string, string> SymbolInfoText
{
    get
    {
        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Error", "No Item Selected" } };
        }
        return selectedItem.GenerateObjectProperties(CurrentLocation, LocalMapManager.Map.Heading);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the error in our code. As per you are description this is not a problem with the binding. This is something related to the data in the `Dictionary`. Please update your post with compete code of your `.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding items post-factum (after the application is launched and the binding link established), then `Dictionary<string,string>` won't be the best choice because it does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Try setting the `ItemsSource` right after an element is added to the dictionary and you will see that items, in fact, appear in the list, you just need to update the binding.

So yes, `ObservableCollection<T>` would be a much more optimal solution because it does send notifications when a change to the core collection occurs.

Comment: I manually fire an OnPropertyChanged on the SymbolInfoText property though, which is why I'm confused. I added some additional logic back to that property in the question; when an item is selected (and thus selectedItem is no longer null), OnPropertyChanged is called and changes the Dictionary (so that three colons appear instead of just the one). From this, it seems to me that the binding is there, but there's some sort of type error around the string...?

Comment: Looking at your code, there is something inherently wrong with the way you're trying to solve the problem. Why are you checking for the selected item in the property getter? Also, what is selectedItem?

Comment: A good resource for an observable dictionary: http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/ ... If the OP is adamant on using a type of dictionary.

Comment: The `ListView` is displaying information about the `selectedItem`. When the selection changes, the newly selected item is queried for new information (most of which has changed since it was last selected (if ever), hence the newly generated dictionary each time). SelectedItem is a MapPoint, which is an app-specific class.

Comment: I also tried using an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` and encountered the same issue. I'm pretty sure the collection is getting updated correctly - a breakpoint on the debugger shows the getter being called each time `selectedItem` changes, as I expect. It also returns the `Dictionary` I'm expecting, which in turn adds `ListViewItem`s. It just doesn't show anything except the statically specified text (and the correct number of hit tests if I remove the `IsHitTestVisible="False"`).

Comment: There should be some refactoring done in your workflow, but regardless - once the dictionary is modified, and check that there are items in it, do something like `ListView.ItemsSource = SymbolInfoText` and check if items are displayed.

Comment: Nope, but changing to just an `ObservableCollection<string>` and changing the property getter to do convert the `Dictionary` into a single string works just fine. I think there must be some sort of glitch with binding to `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: Not as much a glitch as an implementation problem. Feel free to ping me at dend@outlook.com to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will show you what you want but the way you are using it is not normal way of using collections in WPF

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    public Dictionary<string, string> SymbolInfoText
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Error", "No Item Selected" }, { "Error1", "No Item Selected" } };


        }
    }


}
```